# EWS GetRoomsList doesn't work in Exchange Server 2007 SP1

Tags: api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to programmatically get rooms list (Resource Scheduler) from Exchange Server 2007 SP1.

When I run the code from the following link, 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh532566(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/hh532566%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

get an exception like so:

***The service request GetRoomLists is only valid for Exchange version Exchange2010 or later.***

Any idea how to get the RoomsList in Exchange Server 2007 SP1?

Answer (score 2):

In Exchange 2007 rooms are classified as resources. If you want to get a rooms schedule then you can use the EWS API call GetUserAvailability.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa564001.aspx

When you make this call you need to have the correct alias name for the room/resource your interested in. I have built an application on Ex 2007 which does what your talking about using the availability call.

Comment: Problem is I don't know the correct name of the Rooms/Resources. So need to start with getting a list of all rooms and enumerate them. Know how to do it?

Comment: This could be tricky but a couple of options include. 1) contact your exchange administrator and request the names and aliases of all the resources which have been configured. 2) If you've booked these resources previously through Outlook then select the "New E-mail" option and insert the resource name in the "To" box, then use the "Check Names" option to resolve the correct name. When the name resolves correctly you can then double click and navigate to "Outlook Properties" via the icon that looks like a piece of paper and this will give you the alias and other metadata